# EXCEL How to reverse match to find wildcard

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, wildcard

I have two lists in excel, one with wildcards, one with specific strings.

I want to know for every string which wildcard matches it first.

```
      A                      B            C          D               E
   2 Text                                Wildcard              
   3 The Fries Paradise                  *pizza*       
   4 CrabbyPatty Burger                  *burger*        
   5 Fries Work                          *fries*         
   6 Pizza & Burgers        
   7 Pizzaderia                 
   8 OverloadedFries   

So in B3 should be *fries*, in B4 *burger* etc
```

I can't get my head around the MATCH function to reverse, anybody got an idea?

I already got a working solution thanks to you guys.

However i have also wildcards like this:

```
*delicious * nuggets*
as well as
*great V? softdrink*
```

Any idea how to also get these reverse matched?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array formula:

```
=INDEX($C$3:$C$5,MATCH(1,COUNTIF(A3,$C$3:$C$5),0))
```

Comment: does not work for me (#NV). I altered it like this:
=INDEX(sheet1!A:A,MATCH(1,COUNTIF(sheet2!B2,sheet1!A:A),0))
(example row A is actually sheet2 B, and example row c is actually sheet1 A)

Comment: Very nice solution Rory! Since `COUNTIF` will work with both `*` and `?` wildcards, this should work for all examples given by OP. To prevent array entered > `=INDEX($C$3:$C$7,MATCH(1,INDEX(COUNTIF(A3,$C$3:$C$7),),0))`

Comment: Oh well the version of JvdV works smoothly for me, don't know why only this one but it's great!

Comment: My original was an array formula as mentioned, so has to be entered with Ctrl+Shift+Enter, not just Enter. (unless you have the latest O365 builds)

Answer (score 0):

The array formula didn't work for me. Answer provided by [JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv) in comment section works. Please try as follows:

```
=INDEX($C$3:$C$7,MATCH(1,INDEX(COUNTIF(A3,$C$3:$C$7),),0))
```